# Plotly express: text is "flying in" in animations

Tags: python, animation, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

Added some text (to be displayed on the bars) in a bar chart with animation frames.

And well, the text instead of rising along with the bar (like in the beginning of the GIF when I manually move the slider), flies in from the top left corner at each frame until the bar is big enough to fit in the number.

[image]

Now, tweaking `textposition` in `fig.update_traces()` does *kinda* help. But it limits the text to either `inside` or `outside`. The former is not visible in smaller bars at all and the latter imo doesn't look as good as what auto would've looked like without the flying in.

Here is the code to replicate the problem in a smaller dataset-

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'continent': {127: 'South America',
  128: 'South America',
  129: 'South America',
  130: 'South America',
  131: 'South America',
  105: 'Oceania',
  106: 'Oceania',
  107: 'Oceania',
  108: 'Oceania',
  109: 'Oceania'},
 'date': {127: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  128: Timestamp('2021-03-26 00:00:00'),
  129: Timestamp('2021-04-20 00:00:00'),
  130: Timestamp('2021-05-15 00:00:00'),
  131: Timestamp('2021-06-09 00:00:00'),
  105: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  106: Timestamp('2021-03-26 00:00:00'),
  107: Timestamp('2021-04-20 00:00:00'),
  108: Timestamp('2021-05-15 00:00:00'),
  109: Timestamp('2021-06-09 00:00:00')},
 'total_cases': {127: 20465329.0,
  128: 23470911.0,
  129: 26544779.0,
  130: 29891133.0,
  131: 30634559.0,
  105: 35923.0,
  106: 42208.0,
  107: 46514.0,
  108: 50183.0,
  109: 50805.0}})

px.bar(df, x='continent', y='total_cases', animation_frame=df.date.astype(str), text='total_cases')
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked a long time ago, but I'm still going to answer it. Essentially, since the text doesn't 'fit', it flies. I think that that will make more sense by the time you get to the end of this answer. If you render this code in too small of a space, you can still reproduce the 'flying' effect.

I start out by explaining the code, but at the end of the answer, I've put all the code together in one chunk to make it easier for you to collect.

##### Some background...not all that important to the solution!

Alright, in Python, you've got Plotly Express and Plotly Graph Objects. Express functions are intuitive, simple, and somewhat inflexible. Graph Objects are less intuitive, complex, and extremely flexible. Essentially all express graphs are turned into graph objects in the background.

This answer will use the simplicity of Express, then dump that content into graph objects so that you can stop 'flying' your text.

#### Create some data

First things first---we need to separate the text from the bar chart. Instead of using the height of the bar, we're going to add quite a bit of space between the bar and the text because of the extremely large differences in bar values.

In the data you provided in your question, the range was between 0 and 30M, so I used a 1,000,000 buffer. You may need to adjust that since your original data appears to have twice the range.

I'm going to create the variable `y` to store these values. Then I sorted the data by date since it isn't in the example data. (I'm assuming, of course, this is an expectation. You can remove this, of course.)

```
df['y'] = [1000000] * 10
df.sort_values('date', inplace = True)
```

#### The text trace

I'm using a bar chart, but I've set the opacity to 0. The color is specified because light colors tell Plotly to use black text.

```
fig = px.bar(df, x = 'continent', y = 'y', text = 'total_cases',  opacity = 0,
            # light color despite opacity, so text is black
             color_discrete_sequence = ['aliceblue'],
             animation_frame=df.date.astype('str'))
```

#### The bar trace

I've made two changes from your original call: assigned an object name and removed the `text` argument.

```
fig2 = px.bar(df, x = 'continent', y = 'total_cases', 
              animation_frame=df.date.astype('str'))
```

#### Extracting the animation

Now, we're going to create the frames we need for `graph_objects`. Since we have two traces, I'm going to enumerate them.

```
frames = [   # create two traces for each frame using the two plots
    go.Frame(data = f.data + fig.frames[i].data, name = f.name)
    for i, f in enumerate(fig2.frames)
]
```

#### Consolidating the graphics

Next, we're going to create a new figure using the frames just created and the layout from the bar trace. (It doesn't matter which layout you choose.)

```
# consolidate data into one graph
fig4 = go.Figure(data = frames[0].data, frames = frames, layout = fig2.layout)
```

If you render the plot at this point, you'll see that the text runs off the top of the graph. Animation frames inherently are set to `autorange`, adjusting the y-axis continuously. It will be much better to see a single range for the animation. To do this, set the `fixedrange` to true, then I added the tick arrays (values and labels).

```
fig4.update_yaxes(range = [0, 34000000], fixedrange = True, 
                  ticktext = ["0", "5M", "10M", "10M", "20M", "25M", "30M"],
                  tickvals = [0, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000, 25000000, 30000000])
```

###### FYI regarding tick customization

I'm aware that your range will be different. Instead of writing it all out, you could enumerate the tick values and labels. So if you needed to go to 60M, then you would just need to change the 7 in each of these statements to 13.

For the values (`tickvals`)

```
[x + 50000000 * i for i, x in enumerate([0] * 7)]
```

For the labels (`ticktext`)

```
[str(x + 5 * i) + "M" for i, x in enumerate([0] * 7)]
```

##### Check out the Animation on Code Pen

I used `plotly.io`'s `to_html` and pasted it into a Code Pen. [Check out the animation here.](https://codepen.io/fraupflaume/pen/LYrOXbv)

#### Consolidated Code

Here's all of the code altogether (including the packages you need):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import pandas as pd                      # for the data
from pandas import Timestamp             # for the data
import plotly.express as px

df['y'] = [1000000] * 10 # location for text placement
df.sort_values('date', inplace = True)

fig = px.bar(df, x = 'continent', y = 'y', text = 'total_cases', opacity = 0,
            # light color despite opacity, so text is black
             color_discrete_sequence = ['aliceblue'],
             animation_frame=df.date.astype('str'))

fig1 = px.bar(df, x = 'continent', y = 'total_cases', 
              animation_frame=df.date.astype('str'))

frames = [  # create two traces for each frame using the two plots
    go.Frame(data = f.data + fig.frames[i].data, name = f.name)
    for i, f in enumerate(fig1.frames)
]
# consolidate data into one graph
fig4 = go.Figure(data = frames[0].data, frames = frames, layout = fig.layout)

fig4.update_yaxes(range = [0, 34000000], fixedrange = True, 
                  ticktext = ["0", "5M", "10M", "10M", "20M", "25M", "30M"],
                  tickvals = [0, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000, 25000000, 30000000])

fig4.show()
```